# Nomenclature of branched alkane

Tags: nomenclature

I have a compound named 7-(2,4-dimethyl)hexyl-3-ethyl-5,9,11-trimethyltridecane. I have a few questions:

1. why is it (2,4-dimethyl)hexyl and not (2,4-dimethylhexyl)? I asked this question because I saw a compound named 2,5-dimethyl-4-(2-methylpropyl)heptane, and not 2,5-dimethyl-4-(2-methyl)propylheptane.
2. why is the 7-(2,4-dimethyl)hexyl put before 3-ethyl? Shouldn't hexyl be put after ethyl, because e comes first than h?

Comment: Can you draw out the structure? I'm pretty sure re. point 1, you are correct and the parentheses should go round the whole thing. Re. point 2, the substituent's full name is dimethylhexyl, which starts with d, and d comes before e. Note that this is different from 5,9,11-trimethyl... where the substituent is methyl and the tri just indicates that there's three of it.

Comment: @orthocresol Thanks! Then what about 2,5-dimethyl-4-(2-methylpropyl)heptane? Should it be 2,5-dimethyl-4-(2-methylpropyl)heptane or 4-(2-methylpropyl)-2,5-dimethyl-heptane? Both the substituents start with m?

Comment: That's quite a different question; you should ask a new question.